# Put Link in StyledMenuItem in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-link

I wanted to put `Link` so i can navigate to other pages in react. Why is this not navigating

**CODE**

```
  <StyledMenu
  anchorEl={settingsMenu}
  keepMounted
  open={Boolean(settingsMenu)}
  onClose={handleClose}>

  <StyledMenuItem>
    <ListItemIcon component={Link} to={`/accounts`}>
      <PersonIcon />
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText primary="accounts" />
  </StyledMenuItem>
  <StyledMenuItem component={Link} to={`/orders`}>
    <ListItemIcon>
      <OrderIcon />
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText primary="Orders" />
  </StyledMenuItem>
</StyledMenu>;
```

Comment: what do you mean by this is not navigating? the route is not changing? have you setup your client-side routing correctly? add more code/context to your question

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973. Is putting `component={Link} to={`/orders`}` in `StyledMenuItem` okay? Maybe its not acceptable

Comment: Perhaps. the component prop implementation looks similar to what [Material UI MenuItem](https://material-ui.com/api/menu-item/) has. Is this what you intended to do? is StyledMenuItem your custom component? if so just append `this.props.component` to the JSX

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973. How would i do it? Could you answer it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `<StyledMenuItem>` is your custom component, you can easily do this by wrapping the entire JSX in the `component` prop. For the other props passed to it (e.g., `to`), simply destructure them and place them as props to the new wrapper `component`.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
export default class StyledMenuItem extends Component {
    render() {

        // simply checks to see if a component prop is passed
        let WrapperComponent = this.props.component;
        if (WrapperComponent === undefined) {
            WrapperComponent = React.Fragment;
        }

        return (
            <WrapperComponent {...this.props}>
                {this.props.children}
            </WrapperComponent>
        );
    }
}
```

This somehow imitates the behaviour of [Material UI MenuItem](https://material-ui.com/api/menu-item/) like I previously had written about on my comment.

Comment: I'm sorry but my problem is when i click the StyleMenuItem it would redirect me to a certain route. Pls check my edited question

Comment: Are you using react-router? Check if you've imported correct libraries, Example: `import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';`